# Python Data Scraping

Tags: python, excel

Data Scraping in Pyhton.
Code is working fine but it is showing the error which I mentioned below.
What could be the reason?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xlwt import workbook   

wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_satellites").read())

for row in soup('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter’})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    sheet1.write(row, 0, tds[0].string)
    sheet2.write(row, 1, tds[1].string)    

wb.save('Performance Project.xls')
```

> Error:   File "ProcessingProject.py", line 12
>       SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file ProcessingProject.py on line 12

but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Add this to top of your file

Answer (score 0):

for row in soup('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter’})[0].tbody('tr'):

You used a wrong character as single quote delimiter sign after jquery-tablesorter